# Removing redundant methods in java aspectj output

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

I have several jars that I wish to apply the same set of aspects to (compile time weaving). This works fine, except the aspect's methods are added to each individual jar, thus causing redundant package/class definitions. When doing things like class scanning with things like Jetty, warnings are issued because of these duplicates.

I'd like to:

1. apply aspects to each jar, and have the existing normal code to be altered in the output jar itself.
2. place the the actual aspect classes in a separate jar just once.

Is this possible? I don't see how the current options allow this.

Comment: Counter question: How would the AspectJ compiler know (and how would you know) which JARs are used together in the same class loader or even in the same application? BTW, you have 26k reputation, I guess you know the drill: Show some code and Maven config, then I can maybe spot a problem there. It is kinda difficult to debug prose. I do not even know if you use compile-time or binary weaving. Did you think about load-time weaving as an alternative? Then you have no duplicates, but of course slower start-up time.

Comment: compile time weaving. calling ajc on each jar, to produce a modified jar. Each modified jar has a copy of the aspected code. if there was an -aspectOut option, or something, then that would seemingly solve it.

Comment: There is no such option, also not for skipping output of files **not** woven by AspectJ which is often requested and I also would like to have sometimes. But actually you do not need such an option. I looked into one of my Maven projects using binary weaving, and the aspect classes themselves are not part of the output or part of the subsequently packaged JAR file. Do you must be doing something wrong using the AspectJ compiler. Again: Give me an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I can help you. I cannot debug prose!

Comment: i fixed it by writing an ant task to rip out the duplicate classes.

Comment: Like I said, you must be doing something wrong if you have the aspect classes in the output directory. You never showed any code or explained what you do in enough detail, so your comment about the additional Ant script is not helpful to anyone reading this question.